# Netgear AC600 (aka A6100) wifi dongle, dkms managed, fails in 4.4.0-47 kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel, dkms

I have successfully used a Netgear AC600 (aka A6100) wifi dongle for some time now in my 16.04 system and have also successfully had it managed by dkms, so that it was automatically rebuilt on kernel updates.

On the latest kernel update, to 4.4.0-47-generic, the module was successfully rebuilt and loaded by dkms, but it is completely nonfunctional.  It does not even show up in iwconfig.

Dropping back to 4.4.0-45 kernel restores functionality.

Does anyone know what happened in the new kernel to break this?  Is, perhaps, the rtl8812AU driver included in this kernel?  If so, how do I remove the one dkms built for me?

Thanks for any advice.

Edit:
The output of `modinfo 8812au|grep vermagic` is

`vermagic:  4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686`

The output of `ls -al /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au` is

`ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au': no such file or directory`

Edit 2:

The output of `ls /usr/src` is

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-45          linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic  rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0
linux-headers-4.4.0-47
```

The output of `ls /var/lib/dkms` is

`dkms_dbversion   rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux`

Edit 3:

The output of `dkms status` is

```
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 4.4.0-45-generic, i686: installed
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 4.4.0-47-generic, i686: installed
```

Comment: In terminal, type: `modinfo 8812au|grep vermagic` and `uname -r` and report back.

Comment: ps: also, in terminal, type `ls -al /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au` and report back.

Comment: Done.  The first one looks like it might be a clue.  Should it say 4.4.0-47 instead?

Comment: Yes, there's a bug in the source. In terminal, type `ls /usr/src` and `ls /var/lib/dkms`. Are fairly up to speed on dkms? Based on the answers to these 3 questions, I'll formulate an answer for you in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Edited to add the first 2 answers.  For the third - I got this dkms solution to work by googling and cut and trying, but I'm sure no expert.  This is the first time I have set up a module to be managed by dkms.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to type up an answer. Also give me the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I missed the last part until just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dkms 8812au kernel module has a bug in it, that causes it to be built for the wrong kernel during a Software Update that includes kernel updates.

Specific to your case, do the following:

Download newer source (in zip format) from https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU. Expand the zip and copy the source folder to `/usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.14`. Edit the dkms.conf file and change:

```
MAKE="'make'"
```

to

```
MAKE="'make' KVER=${kernelver}"
```

In terminal (don't bother copy/pasting anything after the #'s, they're just comments for you):

1. `sudo dkms remove rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0 --all` # remove old kernel modules
2. `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0` # delete old source code
3. `sudo dkms add rtl8812au/4.3.14` # add /usr/src source to dkms tree
4. `sudo dkms build rtl8812au/4.3.14` # build the driver
5. `sudo dkms install rtl8812au/4.3.14` # install the driver
6. `dkms status` # check to see that the correct version is installed on the current kernel
7. `modinfo 8812au|grep vermagic` # check for correct vermagic value

Comment: You have to name the folder in /usr/src exactly as I specified...`/usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.14`, and edit the dkms.conf file in that folder.

Comment: Genius.  All the steps worked, and when I unplugged / plugged the dongle, it worked.  Thanks so much for taking the time to write up such a detailed answer.

Comment: Cool! Did you learn something about dkms?

Comment: This seems much like what I did the first time.  This time I'm going to make better notes and look up what each step actually does.  I can pretty much assure you I would not be able to have found the omission in dkms.conf on my own.

Comment: So why don't you fork the github, make the change and then submit the change to diederickdehaas.  I actually made a comment on the rtl8812au-dkms bug with my fix that is very similar4

Comment: @Jeremy31 you should recognize your own work... I just used it for a similar driver issue... giggle. I've seen a few drivers with the same problem, and it's related to the kernel version... ie: rtl8814au... too many for me to fork... I'm not that good... yet... but I'm glad you got a bug fix in for the rtl8812au-dkms in the repos.