# rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master

Tags: drivers

I am pulling my hair out. trying to get this Netgear AC600 working I have done everything I can possibly think of. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 lte this is what I have done so far.I went to several forums on the same issue and tried everything suggested in there. It seems like I did load everything it just when you do a sudo modprobe 8812a you get a FATAL error. see below:

```
~$ cd Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master 
~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ make clean make 

ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build M=/home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master clean make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'   CLEAN   /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/.tmp_versions   CLEAN   /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/Module.symvers make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic' ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ make make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build M=/home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master  modules make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'  CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_security.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_debug.o  CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_io.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_ieee80211.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_mlme.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_wlan_util.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_vht.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_rf.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_recv.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_ap.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_xmit.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_p2p.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_tdls.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_br_ext.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_iol.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_sreset.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_btcoex.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_beamforming.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_odm.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/osdep_service.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_intf.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_com.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_com_phycfg.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_phy.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_dm.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_btcoex.o  CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/hal_hci/hal_usb.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/led/hal_usb_led.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8812PwrSeq.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8821APwrSeq.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_xmit.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_sreset.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_hal_init.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_phycfg.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rf6052.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_dm.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rxdesc.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_cmd.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_halinit.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_led.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_xmit.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_recv.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_ops_linux.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_mp.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/efuse/rtl8812a/HalEfuseMask8812A_USB.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/efuse/rtl8812a/HalEfuseMask8821A_USB.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_debug.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDiv.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDect.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_interface.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_HWConfig.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_EdcaTurboCheck.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DIG.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PathDiv.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RaInfo.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicBBPowerSaving.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PowerTracking.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicTxPower.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/PhyDM_Adaptivity.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_CfoTracking.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_NoiseMonitor.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_ACS.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_FW.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_MAC.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_BB.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_RF.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalPhyRf_8812A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RegConfig8812A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RTL8812A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_FW.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_MAC.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_BB.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalHWImg8821A_RF.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/HalPhyRf_8821A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/phydm_RegConfig8821A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/phydm_RTL8821A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8821a/PhyDM_IQK_8821A.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/platform/platform_ops.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_mp.o   CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.o CC [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_bt_mp.o  LD [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/rtl8812au.o   Building modules, stage 2.   MODPOST 1 modules   CC      /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/rtl8812au.mod.o   LD [M]  /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/rtl8812au.ko make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
    ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo make install [sudo] password for ernest: install -p -m 644 rtl8812au.ko  /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ /sbin/depmod -a 4.4.0-31-generic ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo modprobe 8812au modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic ernest@ernest-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo insmod 8821au insmod: ERROR: could not load module 8821au: No such file or directory ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo modprobe rtl8812a [sudo] password for ernest: modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8812a not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic 
    ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ cd /lib ernest@ernest-System-Product-Name:/lib$ cd /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic ernest@ernest-System-Product-Name:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic$ dir build  kernel         modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.order    modules.symbols      vdso initrd   modules.alias  modules.builtin    modules.dep          modules.devname  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic$ cd /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernal/drivers/net/wireless bash: cd: /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernal/drivers/net/wireless: No such file or directory 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic$ cd /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ dir adm8211.ko  at76c50x-usb.ko  atmel.ko       b43legacy  hostap    iwlwifi mac80211_hwsim.ko   mwl8k.ko  ray_cs.ko  rsi           ti        zd1211rw airo_cs.ko  ath            atmel_pci.ko  brcm80211  ipw2x00   libertas     mediatek       orinoco   realtek    rt2x00        wl3501_cs.ko airo.ko     atmel_cs.ko      b43       cw1200     iwlegacy  libertas_tf  mwifiex        p54  rndis_wlan.ko  rtl8812au.ko  zd1201.ko 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ sudo modprobe rtl8812au 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ sudo insmod rtl8812au insmod: ERROR: could not load module rtl8812au: No such file or directory 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ sudo modprobe 8812a modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812a not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic 
    /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ sudo modprobe rtl8812au.ko modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8812au.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic ernest@ernest-System-Product-Name:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless$ cd /home/ernest/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/ 
    ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo modprobe rtl8812au ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo insmod rtl8812au insmod: ERROR: could not load module rtl8812au: No such file or directory ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$
```

Here is the version specification

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

I have tried what you suggested Chilli555 to find if it is loaded and it is showing something there here are the results I received  when I ran the two commands

First command

```
$ lsmod|grep rtl
rtl8812au            1351680  0
cfg80211              565248  1 rtl8812au
```

Here is the second command.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i rtl
[   21.510408] rtl8812au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   21.514156] RTL871X: module init start
[   21.514164] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
[   21.514166] RTL871X: rtl8812au BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20150128-51
[   21.672590] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[   21.673044] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
[   21.673047] RTL871X: module init ret=0
[   21.724719] rtl8812au 1-10:1.0 wlxa0046026bdb7: renamed from wlan0
[80852.550862] RTL871X: HalPwrSeqCmdParsing: Fail to polling Offset[0x6]=00
[80852.568161] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_uninit(wlxa0046026bdb7)
[80852.616597] RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(1) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 550
[80852.617808] RTL871X: rtw_dev_unload: driver in IPS-FWLPS
[80859.871540] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[80860.939224] rtl8812au 1-10:1.0 wlxa0046026bdb7: renamed from wlan0
[81680.114072] RTL871X: HalPwrSeqCmdParsing: Fail to polling Offset[0x6]=00
[81680.128057] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_uninit(wlxa0046026bdb7)
[81680.194375] RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(1) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 550
[81680.198103] RTL871X: rtw_dev_unload: driver in IPS-FWLPS
[81685.232395] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[81686.297087] rtl8812au 1-10:1.0 wlxa0046026bdb7: renamed from wlan0
[99955.465743] RTL871X: HalPwrSeqCmdParsing: Fail to polling Offset[0x6]=00
[99955.480055] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_uninit(wlxa0046026bdb7)
[99955.530162] RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(1) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 550
[99955.531737] RTL871X: rtw_dev_unload: driver in IPS-FWLPS
[100561.614289] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[100562.681207] rtl8812au 1-10:1.0 wlxa0046026bdb7: renamed from wlan0
[191291.187330] RTL871X: HalPwrSeqCmdParsing: Fail to polling Offset[0x6]=00
[191291.204057] RTL871X: rtw_ndev_uninit(wlxa0046026bdb7)
[191291.257018] RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(1) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 550
[191291.258452] RTL871X: rtw_dev_unload: driver in IPS-FWLPS
```

I can see that rtl8812au is loaded.

I do see in the second command that DriverStopped(1), and I am not sure what this is. I can also see where it says Fail to polling. Please advise.

Comment: Why not install it simply by `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`?

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate, but it may be. In any case, the answer to this question got my AC600 working great.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/848025/netgear-ac600-aka-a6100-wifi-dongle-dkms-managed-fails-in-4-4-0-47-kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the result of your `sudo make install`:

> install -p -m 644 rtl8812au.ko 
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/

The name of the driver you compiled and installed is rtl8812au; it is not 8812au.

Also note that when you properly loaded the module, it did so without error or warning:

> sudo modprobe rtl8812au

You can easily check to see if it is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

And you can check the message logs for any informative clues:

```
dmesg | grep -i rtl
```

If your device is not working, either you built the wrong driver or something else is wrong.

Comment: It is working. I didn't see the Icon a the top and it is  showing my network Thank you for the info it was very helpful.